# Taking value from Excel to python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

Hi I'm a newbie in python and trying to take values from excel file to python array. (Using python 3.6)

I did like below code,

```
file_location = "170515_data.xlsx"

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

x = []

for rownum in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    x.append(sheet.cell(rownum, 1))
```

and output gives me like

```
[number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, number:380.0, ...]
```

I don't want to have `number:` in the array.

How can I take that 'number:' out from array?

Or is there any ways for taking all values of row in each column instead of above code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to actually use the `value` of the cell: the cell holds a lot more than just data: it contains formatting, data type, and other information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, hm.. then I have to change code.. how do I do that instead of cell..? :'(

Comment: Cell is an object. You just have to type `.value` after `cell()`  to get the value from the cell.

Comment: NVM I got it. Thanks @AlexanderHuszagh

Comment: Why don't you use pandas?

Comment: @MrPyCharm is `pandas` more useful than `xlrd`?

Comment: I actually haven't used xlrd but I believe same thing can be achieved in pandas in a more intuitive way. I personally prefer pandas for work related to excel files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. :) I was really stupid...

```
for value in sheet.col_values(1):
    x.append(value)
```

This is how I did it. :) and it gives me an output perfectly.

Comment: You can also call `cell(rownum, 1).value`. Just a heads up that may be more efficient if you have to extract multiple pieces of info from a single cell.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderHuszagh :)